# regex working on sublime text but not in eclipse

Tags: java, regex, sublimetext2, match

I have following code :

```
public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="insert into dossier (CODE_SERVICE ,NUM_DOSSIER , INDICE  )values ('224','25437','24')";
        String dmlRegex = ".*((update|insert|delete).*)";
        Pattern dmlPattern = Pattern.compile(dmlRegex);
        Matcher dmlMatcher = dmlPattern.matcher(s);

        System.out.println("Opération : "+dmlMatcher.group(1));

    }

}
```

But it's not working, with following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
    at ma.ancfcc.dossierMatalabRapport.RegexTest.main(RegexTest.java:15)
```

The problem is that the very same regex is working and matching the whole string on sublime text 2, while that on this script I would get `IllegalStateException` even if I replace `dmlMatcher.group(1)` by `dmlMatcher.group(0)`.

What's wrong with my program ?

Comment: `if (dmlMatcher.find()) { System.out.println("Opération : "+dmlMatcher.group(1)); }`

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor :) solved :)

Comment: @mounaim also simplify your regex to `(update|insert|delete)`

Comment: I want the whole DML statement :)